# Issue with Dolby API Integrated with GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, dolby, dolby-audio-api

I'm currently trying to use Dolby's enhance API and I'm running into an issue when trying to write the output file. Here's the code I'm using to get the blob for the input and output blobs:

```
file = await storage_client.get_capture_file(capture.filename)
input_file = file.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    method="GET",
)
blob = storage_client.capture_bucket.blob(
    "{}_{}".format(preset, capture.filename)
    if preset
    else "{}_{}_{}_{}_{}".format(
        speech_isolation,
        range_control,
        noise_reduction,
        peak_limit,
        capture.filename,
    )
)
output_file = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    method="PUT",
    content_type="application/octet-stream",
)
```

The input file works fine since if I write to Dolby's temporary storage, there's no problem. Here's my payload and API call

```
payload = {
    "content": {"type": "mobile_phone"},
    ...
    
    "input": input_file,
    "output": output_file,
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-api-key": os.environ.get("DOLBY_API_KEY"),
}
enhance_response = requests.request(
    "POST", "https://api.dolby.com/media/enhance", json=payload, headers=headers
)
```

The specific error I'm receiving is the following:

```
{'path': '/media/enhance', 'status': 'InternalError', 'progress': 43, 'api_version': 'v1.1.2', 'error': {'type': '/problems/internal-error', 'title': 'An internal service error has occurred'}}
```

I believe the issue has something to do with uploading the new file to GCP. I don't really know what the exact issue is though. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider another way of uploading object to Google Cloud Storage which is to make HTTP call to storage.googleapis.com. You can refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#prereq-rest) as your guide. @bballboy8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
content_type="application/octet-stream",
```

and it will work. I received this answer from Dolby tech support after several days of troubleshooting and it is currently working for me.